# How to build and run a AWS Lambda Function image without using dotnet-lamda tools

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to build my dotnet 8 console application and deploy it to AWS Lambda.

The dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:8-preview AS base

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LambdaExample/LambdaExample.csproj", "LambdaExample/"]
RUN dotnet restore "LambdaExample/LambdaExample.csproj"

COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "LambdaExample/LambdaExample.csproj" --configuration Release --output /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "LambdaExample/LambdaExample.csproj" --configuration Release --runtime linux-x64 --self-contained false --output /app/publish -p:PublishReadyToRun=true  

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /var/task
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

CMD ["LambdaExample::LambdaExample.Function::FunctionHandler"]
```

When I deploy this using `dotnet lambda deploy-function` it works fine when running on AWS.

However when I run docker build on this through a gitlab pipeline stage and push that image to my ECR, and then create a lambda function from that image - it does not work.

When trying to test the lambda function in the AWS console I get the error:

`"errorMessage": "2024-01-24T08:18:16.454Z 8faa9dc0-4971-4d1a-9cd5-f1bce72caeed Task timed out after 3.13 seconds"`

This is being built in the pipeline with:

```
  script:
    - docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
```

What am I missing to enable my pipeline built image to work on Lambda? I have ensured my manually created Lambda function is using the same execution role and vpc set up as the `dotnet lambda deploy-function` one.

Comment: Are you creating a new lambda function for the ECR image? If so did you remember to update the Timeout and Memory configuration? You have to update these after the lambda function is created. The default Timeout is 3 seconds.

Comment: This turned out to be the problem! I would never have thought - even though it seems so obvious now! I set the timeout higher and now it is running :)

Comment: I have added it as an actual answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember to update the Timeout and Memory configuration? You have to update these after the lambda function is created. The default Timeout is 3 seconds.